# Java program for multiply two matrix (with user input)

Tags: java, function, matrix

Please help guys thats my homework.. Whats wrong ? I cant see any problem ?
No problem for my user input but there are some problems with the function.
I need a java program for multiply two matrix (with user input !!)
Thanks for help !

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class multiply{

   public static int[][] multiply(int[][] x, int[][] y){

      int a, b, c, d, temp = 0, k, first, second, multiply, q, w;
       for ( q = 0 ; q < a ; q++ )
       {
          for ( w = 0 ; w < d ; w++ )
          {   
             for ( k = 0 ; k < c ; k++ )
             {
                temp = temp + first[x][k]*second[k][y];
             }

             multiply[x][y] = temp;
             temp = 0;
          }
       }   
       return multiply[x][y];
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int a, b, c, d, q, w, temp = 0, k;
      int [][]x;
      int [][]y;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter the number of rows and columns of first matrix");
      a = klavye.nextInt();
      b = klavye.nextInt();

      int first[][] = new int[a][b];

      System.out.print("Enter the elements of first matrix:");

      for ( q = 0 ; q < a ; q++ )
         for ( w = 0 ; w < b ; w++ )
             first[q][w] = input.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Enter the number of rows and columns of second matrix:");
      c = input.nextInt();
      d = input.nextInt();

      while (a != d) {
      System.out.print("Matrices with entered orders can't be multiplied with each other.Try again:");
      c = input.nextInt();
      d = input.nextInt();
      }
      {
         int second[][] = new int[c][d];

         System.out.print("Enter the elements of second matrix");

         for ( q = 0 ; q < c ; q++ )
            for ( w = 0 ; w < d ; w++ )
                second[q][w] = input.nextInt();



         for ( q = 0 ; q < a ; q++ )
         {
            for ( w = 0 ; w < d ; w++ )
               System.out.print("Product of entered matrices:" +multiply(x,y));

            System.out.print("\n");

         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: NASA has/had a publicly available Matrix class which you might want to use instead or to check your implementation against: https://gitorious.org/worldwind/worldwind/source/a7b406ade6c69484950ef9b99523e571169b5598:src/gov/nasa/worldwind/geom/Matrix.java

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, the `multiply` method should return a matrix, not a cell of the matrix, so change

```
return multiply[x][y];
```

to

```
return multiply;
```

Oh, and your `multiply` variable should be an `int[][]`, not an `int`.

I would also avoid using the same identifier - `multiply` - for both the class name, the method and a local variable inside the method. This could give the compiler a hard time in some cases. Use different names.

And there are tons of other errors...

`x` and `y` are the input matrices, not indices. `first` and `second` are meaningless local int variables, not the input matrices. etc...